# ElasticeSearch JavaScript API Query with space

Tags: javascript, json, elasticsearch

The following was how I created my data.

Step 1:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/customers"
```

Step 2:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/customers/object/_mapping" -d "{
  \"object\": {
    \"properties\": {
      \"customerid\": {
        \"type\": \"long\",
        \"index\": \"not_analyzed\"
      },
      \"customername\": {
        \"type\": \"string\",
        \"index\": \"not_analyzed\"
      },
      \"address\": {
        \"type\": \"string\",
        \"index\": \"not_analyzed\"
      }
    }
  }
}"
```

Step 3: insert the following data to the index:

```
[
  {
    "customerid": "100001",
    "customername": "Daniilu Bas",
    "address": "39 Easy Shadow Concession"
  },
  {
    "customerid": "100002",
    "customername":"Markos Roberts",
    "address":"4823 Quiet Mall"
  },
  {
    "customerid": "100003",
    "customername": "John Roberts Faruk",
    "address": "464 Harvest Passage"
  }
]
```

After this, I searched the customername "John Roberts Faruk" through elasticsearch javascript client api. This was the query that I used.

elasticRequest = {[{body:[{query:{match:{customername: "John Roberts Faruk"}}}, {size:1000}]}, index: "customers", type: "object"]}

The return included two customer names, "Markos Roberts" and "John Roberts Faruk".

This was not what I wanted. I wanted it matching with "John Roberts Faruk" only.

Did I do something wrong in the search query?

Comment: Sorry, this query will not return any result.

Comment: Do you see the correct mapping when you try to retrieve it from Elastic (i.e. to check that the mapping was created successfully)?

Comment: Yes, I did check it and it seemed correct. This was what I saw... {
"customers": {
"mappings": {
"object": {
"properties": {
"address": {
"type": "string",
"index": "not_analyzed"
},
"customerid": {
"type": "long"
},
"customername": {
"type": "string",
"index": "not_analyzed"
}
}
}
}
}
}